# In 'initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

So I have the class 'Range' created by Datamapper (this is in a Ruby/Sinatra project):

```
class Range
  include DataMapper::Resource
  #properties
  property :id, Serial, :key => true
  property :default_gateway, String
  property :subnetmask, String
  property :main_ip, String
  property :backup_ip, String
  property :dhcp, String
  #relations
  belongs_to :vlan, :required => true
  has n, :dhcp
end #class Range
```

I also have a file 'initdata' which I call in my main class. A part of this file tries to fill up the database with some dummy data. The problem is with the class Ranges it gives me an ArgumentError.

Initdata ruby file:

```
#CREATE RANGES
if Range.count == 0
  puts '----- ADDING RANGES -----'
  range1 = Range.first_or_create(:default_gateway => '10.1.2.44', :subnetmask => '0.0.255.255', :main_ip => '10.1.0.1', :backup_ip => '10.1.0.2', :dhcp => '192.168.1.2', :vlan_id => 1)
  range1.errors.each do |error|
    puts error
  end
end
```

I get the following error when I run it in the terminal:

```
----- ADDING RANGES -----
/home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/dm-validations-1.2.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:129:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3) (ArgumentError)
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/dm-validations-1.2.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:129:in `new'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/dm-validations-1.2.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:129:in `create'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/model.rb:444:in `first_or_create'
    from /home/bene/project/development_sam/lan_portal/dal/initdata.rb:328:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bene/project/development_sam/lan_portal/app.rb:6:in `require'
    from /home/bene/project/development_sam/lan_portal/app.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bene/project/development_sam/lan_portal/config.ru:1:in `require'
    from /home/bene/project/development_sam/lan_portal/config.ru:1:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/bene/project/development_sam/lan_portal/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/bene/project/development_sam/lan_portal/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/bene/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong? I've searched for it, but most solutions are because people wrote their own 'initialize' function, as in my case, it's already defined by DataMapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a core Ruby class [Range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Range.html#method-c-new) (which, incidentally, has a 2..3-argument constructor); Appearently, DataMapper does not redefine a constructor if one already exists.

You need to rename your class.